# stochastic dominance displaced diffusions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose I have two processes both satisfying a displace lognormal diffusion:
$$
dX(t) = \alpha(t)[X(t) - a] dW(t)
$$
$$
dY(t) = \beta(t)[Y(t) - b] dW(t)
$$
Note that the processes are perfectly correlated where $W(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion, $\alpha, \beta$ are deterministic functions of time, and $a,b$ are constants greater than zero.

Under what conditions will their difference be greater than zero at all times?:
$$
p X(t) - q Y(t) \geq 0 \quad p,q \in \mathcal{R}, p > q > 0
$$
Initially at $t=0$ I know that their difference as written above is greater than zero. Are there simple conditions on $\alpha,\beta,a,b$ that ensure the difference is always positive?

Comment: I think $qY(y)$ is a typo? probably supposed to be $qY(t)$?

Comment: @Sanjay good spot, thanks. I edited it.

Comment: Why do you say that the inequality holds at $t=0$, given that you do not have any information for $X(0)$ and $Y(0)$? Note that, both $X-a$ and $Y-b$ are lognormal, I doubt there are any meaningful conditions for this to hold in general.

Comment: @Gordon because at t=0 X and Y are market observables satisfying the positivity condition. I am basically working on a model for X and Y.

Answer (score 1):

You can have explicite solution of $X_t$ and $Y_t$. 
Put $V_t = \ln{(X_t-a)}$, we can easily find the equation of $V_t$:
$$dV_t = -\frac{1}{2}\alpha_t^2 dt+\alpha_tdW_t$$
So,
$$V_t = V_0 -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t{\alpha_s^2 ds}+\int_0^t{\alpha_sdW_s}$$
Hence
$$X_t = a + (x_0-a)\exp{(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t{\alpha_s^2 ds}+\int_0^t{\alpha_sdW_s})}$$

The next step is to find the condition that
$$Z_t = pX_t -qY_t=(pa-qb) +p(x_0-a)\exp{(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t{\alpha_s^2 ds}+\int_0^t{\alpha_sdW_s})} -q(y_0-b)\exp{(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t{\beta_s^2 ds}+\int_0^t{\beta_sdW_s})} \geq 0$$

I think that you can solve it easily.

Comment: Thanks, I must be missing something but how does your expression for $Z_t$ lead to an 'easy' solution?

Comment: Juste put  $A =\int_0^t{\alpha_sdW_s} $ and $B =\int_0^t{\beta_sdW_s} $. You have $(A_t,B_t)$ follows the gaussian distribution with 
$V(A) = \int_0^t{\alpha_s^2ds}$, $V(B) = \int_0^t{\beta_s^2ds}$ and $CoV(A,B) = \int_0^t{\alpha_s\beta ds}$
You solve the equation
$$\exp(A)-z_1\exp(B) \geq z_2$$

Comment: Yes but that would be a numerical solution right? That's fine, but it's not an 'easy' algebraic relation. I need to think about your solution for a bit.

Comment: No, not numerical solution. You can have explicite algebric solution.
Hint: You decompose $A$ and $B$ to:
$$A = m_1 C +m_2 D$$
$$B = m_3 C +m_4 D$$
with $C$ and $D$ are independant and following the standard gaussian distribution.
put
$$f(c,d) = \exp(m_1 c + m_2 d) - z_1 \exp(m_3 c + m_4 d) - z_2 $$
you find the conditions on $m_i$ and $z_1$ ,$ z_2$ by calculating the min of f.  
$$$$

Tell me if the solution is ok.
PS: Sorry for my english and my latex. For long time I don't practice them.

Comment: Thank you - I am going to sit down tomorrow morning and work on your solution. Will get back to you.

Comment: The idea is to find the minimum of the function of 2 variables $f(c,d)$ and its miminum must be greater than $0$. $$$$
You solve the two equations system of first partial derivatives of $f$ to find the critial point and this critital point must be the minimum of the function $f$ (you check the matrix of second derivatives, this matrix must be positive definite).

Comment: There is a large amount of calculation. 
$$$$
It seems to me that the function $f$ doesn't have critical point (we suppose that we are not in the degenerate case where $X_t =Y_t$).$$$$ If yes, you should check the value of $f$ at the boundary (in this exercise, the boundary is $-\inf$ and $+\inf$ for $c$ and $d$).

Comment: Thanks, please see my answer to my own question.

Comment: I don't see your answer. Perhaps you deleted it?